# C++ non-qualified lookup

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup, unqualified-name

I have the following code:

```
//mystd plays a role of the std namespace
//which does not allow any new overloads in it
//so we define one in the global namespace
namespace mystd {

template<typename T>
struct A {};

}

//if one uncomment this, everything works as designed
//int f(const mystd::A<int>& v);

//this some namespace which is supposed to be the main one
namespace a {

template<typename T>
int f(const T& v) {
  return 0;
}

template<typename T>
int operator-(const T& v) {
  return 0;
}

}

//this should be different from ::a
//so that `using namespace a;` would import global functions 
//as well as all functions from namespace a, since 
//the global namespace is the nearest common namespace
//see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/dcl.html#namespace.udir 
namespace b {

template<typename T>
int Call(const T& v) {
  using namespace ::a;
  return -v + f(v);
}

}

int operator-(const mystd::A<int>&) {
  return 1;
}
int f(const mystd::A<int>&) {
  return 2;
}

int main() {
  //why this returns 1, not 3?
  //what is the difference between operator-() & f()?
  return b::Call(mystd::A<int>());
}
```

The idea is to imitate the behavior of gtest operator<< & PrintTo, so that one could overload behaviour for some std classes, which can not be done through ADL since adding anything to std namespace is not allowed. However, if I try to do it with a usual function `f()`, then the overload for `f(mystd::A())` is considered to be defined too late (if one comments the template definition of `f()` the gcc gives `note: ‘int f(const mystd::A<int>&)’ declared here, later in the translation unit`)

The question is why the behaviour is different for `operator-()` and `f()`?

Comment: [The return value is 0 if compiled with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b51e48dbada84a3)

Comment: Actually, I discovered that results are different in clang (returns 0), gcc (gives 1) & visual studio (gives 3). Is that an UB?

Comment: It's more like bugs in some (or all) of these three compilers. It is quite well-known that VS doesn't implement the correct name lookup rule for names in templates.

Comment: "`using namespace a;` would import global functions as well as all functions from namespace a" - no, that's not what that quote says. A *using directive* doesn't really import anything; for unqualified name lookup, it makes the names in the designated namespace appear *as if* they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace [...]; in this case, that namespace is the global namespace. So, within that `return` statement in `Call`, the two templates declared in `a` appear as if they were declared in the global namespace, because the lookup for both involves unqualified lookup.

Comment: Clang is right in my opinion; the result should be `0`. In this case, the lookup for `operator -` should be the same as for `f`. The key rules are in [14.6.4.2] ([temp.dep.candidate]), first bullet point in particular. Sorry, I don't have time for a proper answer at the moment; if nobody else provides one, I'll write one later on.

Comment: @bogdan Thanks, looks like you are right with the causes. I was confused by the fact that this (using namespace) was used in gtest and they claim it does work (see gtest/gtest-printers.h). However, when I actually tried to define my own behaviour for outputting std:vector<int>, then it did not work and they used their own printers.

Comment: try `using a::f;` and `using a::operator-;`

Comment: @celtschk While that changes the underlying mechanism through which those names become visible in `Call`, it doesn't change the outcome in this case - the result should still be `0` in a correct implementation.

Comment: @DmitryPanteleev I suppose you're referring to `DefaultPrintNonContainerTo` in `gtest-printers.h`. That will only work correctly if you declare your `operator <<` before you include the `gtest` header, making it visible in the definition context of their template. The fact that it works with later declarations of operator overloads is, as far as I can tell, a bug in GCC (and MSVC, but it's well-known that MSVC doesn't implement dependent name lookup properly).

Comment: @DmitryPanteleev As far as your overload for `std::vector<int>` not being picked up, that happened for a different reason: look at the comments in the definition of the `PrintTo` template (line 357 in trunk). The tests for whether the type is a container happen first, before getting to the other mechanism in `DefaultPrintNonContainerTo` (hence the name), because they want their format to be used for standard containers. It looks like you're not supposed to change that.

Comment: Anyway, regarding your original question, is everything clear regarding the standard behaviour for that lookup, or could you still use a complete answer?

Comment: @bogdan No, everything works like you've explained. And here is the bug in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577

The answer is useful only as something I could mark as correct